# Swing buttons overlapping

Tags: java, database, jbutton, flat-file

So I am trying to make a sort of flat-file database for school in Java. To input the student Info, I use Jbuttons. My problem is that the Buttons are on top of each other and you can't click on. Code:

```
package hsqi;

import java.util.Random;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import static java.lang.System.out;

public class PopUp {

public static void main(final String[] args) {

    String hsqi = "School";
    File fl = new File(hsqi);
    if (!fl.exists()) {
        System.out.println("Creating... ");
        fl.mkdir();
    } else {
        System.out.println("Main File already exists!");
    }

    Random rand = new Random();
    int value = rand.nextInt(10000);
    System.out.println("Student ID is: " + value);

    final JFrame parent = new JFrame();
    JButton button = new JButton();

    button.setText("Add Student");
    parent.add(button);
    parent.pack();
    parent.setVisible(true);

    button.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(parent, "Student Name: ", null);
            String flName = "C:\\Users\\Saeed\\Workspace1\\Database\\School\\" + name;
            File newFile = new File(flName);
            if(!newFile.exists()){  
                System.out.println("Creating user Profile...");
                newFile.mkdir();
            }else{
               System.out.println("Profile already exists!");   
            }   

            PrintWriter writer;
            try {
                writer = new PrintWriter(flName);
                writer.println(name);
                writer.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        JButton button = new JButton();

        button.setText("Add Student");
        parent.add(button);
        parent.pack();
        parent.setVisible(true);
        button.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                    String Grade = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(parent, "Grade: ", null);
                    String fname = "C:\\Users\\Saeed\\Workspace1\\Database\\School\\" + name + Grade ;
                    File newnewFile = new File(fname);
                    if(newnewFile.exists()){
                        System.out.println("Creating user Profile...");

                    }else{
                      System.out.println("Profile already exists!");}

                    PrintWriter writer;
                    try {
                        writer = new PrintWriter(fname);
                        writer.println(Grade);
                        writer.close();
                    } catch (Exception e) {}
                    }

                });
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I just need to know how to make the second button pop up as soon as the first is clicked and the and the information is put in.

Comment: Also it's not making the Grade.txt file

Comment: Why are you importing the JavaFX classes when you don't use them. This is a pure swing application, not a JavaFX application.